# webpy radio buttons

Tags: radio-button, web.py

I'm using webpy to create a web page and I needed to use a radio button to do some conditionals, I couldn't find any documentation on this and Just wanted to know how to use fow control like : `if radio1.checked() : do stuff`

any help would be great I'm new to dweb programming

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like this:

```
radio_button = form.Form( 
    form.Radio('details', ['option1', 'option2', 'option3', 'option4']),
    )
```

Also, you can just have webpy render an html page and put the radio button html tag into that page.  I would suggest that you don't try to learn how to use webpy's templating system if you are new to programming.  It is too abstract for a beginner.  Instead use webpy to serve your pages and write your pages in a regular manner.  Then when you feel comfortable you should consider a nice standalone template engine like Jinja2.

This has also been answered here:

[How to use radio buttons in python web.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12816464/how-to-use-radio-buttons-in-python-web-py)

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure Paxwell misread what you wanted to do. I have my radio buttons sent over ajax inside of a big form.

The html looks like this

```
<form> 
    ... form stuff...
    <div class="control-group">         
      <div class="controls">    
         <label class="radio">
          <input type="radio" name="radioId" value="option1" checked>
               Reporter 1
          </label>
         <label class="radio">
           <input type="radio"  name="radioId" value="option2" 
              Reporter 2
         </label>  
        ..
        </div>
     </div>
 </form>
```

my main.py:

```
def POST(self):
form = web.input()
```

after experimenting, the radio buttons will be inside of the form! I have named my radio buttons with **the same name**. when you select:
`form.radio_id`, it will only return the value of the checked one. in this case you will get  `option1`

```
radiobutton= "%s" % (form.radioId)
if radiobutton == "option1":
    print "hooray!"
```