# How to use radio buttons in python web.py

Tags: python, radio-button, web.py

I am using web.py framework to create a simple web application

I want to create a radio button so I wrote the following code

```
from web import form
from web.contrib.auth import DBAuth
import MySQLdb as mdb



render = web.template.render('templates/')

urls = (
  '/project_details',  'Project_Details',  
)

class Project_Details:

    project_details = form.Form( 
        form.Radio('Home Page'),
        form.Radio('Content'),
        form.Radio('Contact Us'),
        form.Radio('Sitemap'),
        )

    def GET(self):
        project_details = self.project_details()
        return render.projectdetails(project_details)
```

When I run the code with url `localhost:8080` I am seeing following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 237, in process
    return p(lambda: process(processors))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 565, in processor
    h()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 661, in __call__
    self.check(mod)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 680, in check
    reload(mod)
  File "/home/local/user/python_webcode/index.py", line 68, in <module>
    class Project_Details:
  File "/home/local/user/python_webcode/index.py", line 72, in Project_Details
    form.Radio('password'),
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
```

What parameter need to be passed in the radio button in order to avoid this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/webpy/webpy/blob/master/web/form.py#L291), it looks like you have to use one `Radio` constructor for all of your items as the same `Radio` object will actually generate multiple `<input>` elements.

Try something like::

```
project_details = form.Form( 
    form.Radio('details', ['Home Page', 'Content', 'Contact Us', 'Sitemap']),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I was able to decipher.  checked='checked' seems to select a random (last?) item in the list. Without a default selection, my testing was coming back with a NoneType, if none of the radio-buttons got selected.

```
project_details = form.Form(
  form.Radio('selections', ['Home Page', 'Content', 'Contact Us','Sitemap'], checked='checked'),
  form.Button("Submit") 
)
```

To access your user selection as a string...

```
result = project_details['selections'].value
```

If you want to use javascript while your template is active, you can add, onchange='myFunction()' to the end of the Radio line-item. I'm also assigning an id for each element, to avoid frustration with my getElementById calls, so my declaration looks like this.

```
 project_details = form.Form(
   form.Radio('selections', ['Home Page', 'Content', 'Contact Us','Sitemap'], checked='checked', onchange='myFunction()', id='selections'),
   form.Button("Submit") 
)
```